# can i change out (2) 30-amp breakers with (2)40 amp breakers

Tags: electrical

replacing water heater with a tankless one, breakers have to be (2) 40 amp I have (2)30 amp breakers now the electric wire is 10-2

Answer (score 6):

Not unless you also replace the wires with 8 AWG wires, or whatever size is called for in the manufacturer's installation instructions.